# Algolia DocSearch in Docusaurus doesn't bring any results

Tags: algolia, docusaurus

my docs-site got approved from Algolia and their crawler also was able to index a few hundred records there, so that side seems to work.
In my `docusauras.config.js` I have added the following under `themeConfig`:

```
algolia: {
  appId: '7********C',
  apiKey: '9*****************************5',
  indexName: 'o******t',
  contextualSearch: true,
},
```

Now the search bar at the top of the site appears but it does not find anything when searching: `No results for "xyz"` ; whatever I search for (which's on the site ...)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? The `apiKey` is the "Search API Key", right?

Unsuccessfull search on site:

[image]

Algolia: Application interface (API):

[image]

Invitation/Confirmation mail from Algolia:
[mail from Algolia]

[image]

Comment: did you do a manual indexing with your algolia account or did you apply for an api key from https://docsearch.algolia.com/apply/

Comment: I did it via applying with your link. (and got approved ...)

Comment: i havent done that way so dont know the procedure. do they give you an account login or just an apiKey. anyway in the config file can you check if it works with only apiKey and indexName (without appId)

Comment: No, appId is a necessity. Otherwise e.g. npm throws an error:
`[ERROR] ValidationError: "algolia.appId" is required.`

Comment: I got an email with an "invitation" that when I clicked on had to create an account and in this account my application for indexing was magically created :)
That's the mail https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxtoR.png

Don't wonder for the API key, I (accidentally) regenerated it one time, so now there's another one but the one in my docusaurus config matches the "Search API Key" on the algolia dashboard.

Comment: hmm have you looked at github issues for eg https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/7647

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [cmgchess suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72838375/algolia-docsearch-in-docusaurus-doesnt-bring-any-results/72840792#comment128656173_72838375), that's the issue I had:
https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/7647

The problem is a recent update of Docusaurus, since which contextual search is enabled by default. The problem: Algolia's default config for Docusaurus v1 and older Docusaurus v2 versions didn't have an option for this attribute to configure the crawler.

To solve:

1. Delete the current index
2. Copy the new v2 config from https://docsearch.algolia.com/docs/templates/#docusaurus-v2-template or directly create the crawler at https://crawler.algolia.com/admin/crawlers/create
3. Re-run crawler (will create an index).
4. Redeploy the Docusaurus site.